# How to automate audio editing?

Tags: applescript, audio, automator

I want to make audio editing workflows in Automator. My current goal: to cut out exactly the same length from a group of audio files.

I haven't found any audio editors supporting AppleScript yet. Other kinds of scripts/solutions are also welcome.

Comment: can you share what have you done so far?

Comment: Hmm… just a ton of googling. This would be my first AppleScript/Automator task, and I do not know where can I find the AppleScript capable apps or their AppleScript reference.
One thing is for sure, Ableton Live 8 supports AppleScript (and I have Ableton Live 8 installed): https://forum.ableton.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=204195&start=0

Comment: You could use python instead.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), run `brew install ffmpeg`, and then run something like

`cd ~/containing/folder;for f in *.aif;do /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -ss 0:12:34 -t 0:0:5 -c copy "${f%.aif}-clip.aif";done`

where `-ss 0:12:34` is the starting position and `-t 0:0:5` is the duration.

Answer (score -1):

MYRIAD Worth a Play…

Apple Script enables and VERY slick

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on what you meant by MYRIAD? Is there something you can link to, just so there's no confusion about your answer? Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.